# different user id different show

Tags: android, authentication

hi i want to make different user menu when they login

first i created this code

```
String USER_TYPE_1 = "poeja";
```

then i make it like this code

```
   if(tv_name.equals(pref.getString(USER_TYPE_1,""))){
        tv_id.setText(pref.getString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, ""));
    }
```

in there i want to show UNIQUE_ID to user "poeja", but it gave me nothing and also no error in android stuido but the unique_id never show in there.

did i miss something?
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
if(tv_name.getText().toString().trim().equals(pref.getString(USER_TYPE_1,""))){
    tv_id.setText(pref.getString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, ""));
}
```

make sure your pref not returning null